# A Dynkin type classification result in linear algebra

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, graph-theory, matrices

Let $G$ be a finite directed acyclic graph. The Cartan matrix $C_G=C$ of $G$ is defined as the matrix with rows and colums indexed by the vertices of $G$ and $c_{i,j}$ counts the number of paths from $i$ to $j$.
The Coxeter matrix of $G$ is defined by $\Phi_G=\Phi=- C^{-1}C^T$.
Call a matrix $M$ periodic if $M^k=\mathrm{id}$ for some $k \geq 1$. Call $G$ periodic if $\Phi_G$ is periodic.
The following gives a Dynkin type classification in linear algebra/graph theory:

> Theorem: $G$ is periodic if and only if $G$ is of (simply laced) Dynkin type.

> Question 1: Is there a direct (and easy) linear algebra proof of this result (in the literature)? At least in the case when $G$ is a tree (as an undirected graph) an elementary/quick proof might be possible.

> Question 2: The Coxeter matrix is well known from representation theory, but does it also appear in a purely graph theoretic context in a natural way?

> Question 3: Who was the first to notice this result?